# How can I make these two Calendars show up next to eachother?

Tags: html, css, date, calendar, alignment

I have two simple HTML table calendars but for some reason they're not next to each other. How can I make them side by side? Here's the code I haver right now:

```
<div class="title">June 2014</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">1</span></td><td><span class="date">2</span></td><td><span class="date">3</span></td><td><span class="date">4</span></td><td><span class="date">5</span></td><td><span class="date">6</span></td><td><span class="date">7</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">8</span></td><td><span class="date">9</span></td><td><span class="date">10</span></td><td><span class="date">11</span></td><td><span class="date">12</span></td><td><span class="date">13</span></td><td><span class="date">14</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">15</span></td><td><span class="date">16</span></td><td><span class="date">17</span></td><td><span class="date">18</span></td><td><span class="date">19</span></td><td><span class="date">20</span></td><td><span class="date">21</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">22</span></td><td><span class="date">23</span></td><td><span class="date">24</span></td><td><span class="date">25</span></td><td><span class="date">26</span></td><td><span class="date">27</span></td><td><span class="date">28</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">29</span></td><td><span class="date">30</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
</table>
<p>
<div class="title">July 2014</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">1</span></td><td><span class="date">2</span></td><td><span class="date">3</span></td><td><span class="date">4</span></td><td><span class="date">5</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">6</span></td><td><span class="date">7</span></td><td><span class="date">8</span></td><td><span class="date">9</span></td><td><span class="date">10</span></td><td><span class="date">11</span></td><td><span class="date">12</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">13</span></td><td><span class="date">14</span></td><td><span class="date">15</span></td><td><span class="date">16</span></td><td><span class="date">17</span></td><td><span class="date">18</span></td><td><span class="date">19</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">20</span></td><td><span class="date">21</span></td><td><span class="date">22</span></td><td><span class="date">23</span></td><td><span class="date">24</span></td><td><span class="date">25</span></td><td><span class="date">26</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="date">27</span></td><td><span class="date">28</span></td><td><span class="date">29</span></td><td><span class="date">30</span></td><td><span class="date">31</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it. Place them in *containers*:

```
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="title">June 2014</div>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
<div class="calendar">
    <div class="title">July 2014</div>
    <table>...</table>
</div>
```

And make those containers display as *inline-blocks*:

```
.calendar {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/tE5VG/)**

They will stay side by side *as long as the page width fits both side by side*.

If you want them to *always* be side by side, even if they don't fit in the window (you would need to scroll sideways), then place the containers inside an external container containing both of them, and make the width of that container be a *fixed* size that fits both calendars.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below. Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J49zk/)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="title">June 2014</div>
            < -- Your Table content for June 2014 -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="title">July 2014</div>
            < -- Your Table content for July 2014 -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the complete code ..

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="title">June 2014</div>
            <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="date">1</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">2</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">3</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">4</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">5</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">6</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">7</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="date">8</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">9</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">10</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">11</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">12</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">13</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">14</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="date">15</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">16</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">17</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">18</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">19</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">20</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">21</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="date">22</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">23</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">24</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">25</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">26</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">27</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">28</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="date">29</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">30</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
        <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="title">July 2014</div>
             <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">1</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">2</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">3</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">4</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">5</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="date">6</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">7</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">8</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">9</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">10</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">11</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">12</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="date">13</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">14</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">15</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">16</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">17</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">18</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">19</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="date">20</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">21</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">22</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">23</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">24</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">25</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">26</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><span class="date">27</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">28</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">29</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">30</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">31</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td><span class="date">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```